# Is it possible to fit a 5000 litre tank on a normal rooftop?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture, storage

I currently have a 750 litre overhead water tank installed. Is it possible to install a 5000 litre water tank in the same place? Would the weight be a concern? The house is a two storied buliding bulit on a 1200 square feet site. The total height of building is about 23 feet. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: So you want to replace a tank that weighs about 1000kg with one that is 5 times heavier? Get it checked by an architect or engineer.

Comment: Closer to 7 times heavier (the contents 6.667 and then the empty tank will weigh more too.) You could very easily go from 23 feet / 7 meters high to a pile of rubble a few feet/meters high, with loss of life. Definite need for a structural/civil engineer assessment. A safer alternative might be a ground level tank for more storage and a pump to the existing tank.

Answer (score 5):

You need a structural engineer. There is no way for us to judge the stability of your roof

Answer (score 0):

750 litres weighs -- well I'll spare you the gory math as it would make the answer too long, but it comes out to 750 kilograms or 1650 pounds.   **Or the weight of a small car**.

Now I wouldn't put that on *my* roof without architectural review.

Now, you propose to put a 5000 litre tank there, which is 5000 kilograms (11,000 lbs).  **Or the weight of a semi tractor**.

[image]

So no... even the 750l tank is a risk.  You need an engineer to certify and/or reinforce the building.

Comment: but, without an overhead tank, can we get running water for daily use? I think every office or residential building should have an overhead tank

Comment: @vidyarthi Just have a competent engineer either certify the building or reinforce it.  Alternately you can make the tank smaller or use several small tanks.  A 100l tank weighs about the same as a human, you can have several spread out and connect the bottoms; they'll act like one big tank.  A smaller tank just means needing to refill more often.  If on-site storage is an issue, the big tank could be downstairs.  Flush toilets and wash water are a huge boon to survival and quality of life esp. children, *but it defeats the purpose if the building falls on your head*.